# Change Clang's colored output

Tags: bash, clang, diagnostics

Is it possible to change Clang's choice of colors for their colorized diagnostics?
I like my terminal to have a black background, but I just noticed that I was missing Clang's helpful diagnostic messages.  I'm aware of the the -fno-color-diagnostics compiler option but I would prefer to have the colors, just different colors.  Any solutions?
I'm using a bash shell in OSX.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the colors are hard-coded near the beginning of [this file](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/TextDiagnostic_8cpp_source.html) ([include file](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/include/llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h?revision=154805&view=markup)). You can edit the file and recompile the program, write and submit a feature that accepts color settings at the command line, in an environment variable or from a file, or non-portably try to substitute the colors on the fly.

Here is an example of the latter:

```
clang ... | sed 's/\o33\[30m/\o33[37m/g'
```

That changes black to white for XTerm escape sequences. Some other sequence would need to be used for other terminal types.